# XSD Enumeration representation

Tags: xml, xsd

I am completely new to XML and XSD Schemes.  I have the below XSD:

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <xs:element name="OutcomesData">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Outcome">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Customers">
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Title" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

However, I need to represent the enumerations for Title (e.g. Mr, Mrs, Miss, Ms) in the above XSD - How do I do this?  Is the below correct?

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="OutcomesData">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Outcome">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Customers">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Title" type="xs:string" />
                       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:enumeration value="Dr"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="Lord"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="Miss"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="Mr"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="Mrs"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="Ms"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="Sir"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

A lot of examples on the internet mention 'Simple Type' but I am using 'Complex Type' - does this make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various syntax issues with your schema. You have xsd namespace prefixes that are not declared in the schema element, these should probably be just xs.  And your elements aren't nested correctly.  You will probably also want to set a default and targetNamespace.

You can just use simpleType for the Title.

Find below a valid schema that might be what you are after.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.SO58286917b" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.SO58286917b" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="OutcomesData">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Outcome">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Customers">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Title">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:enumeration value="Dr" />
                          <xs:enumeration value="Lord" />
                          <xs:enumeration value="Miss" />
                          <xs:enumeration value="Mr" />
                          <xs:enumeration value="Mrs" />
                          <xs:enumeration value="Ms" />
                          <xs:enumeration value="Sir" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```